# How would a native speaker understand buying 2 socks?

Tags: meaning, phrases

How would a native speaker understand this sentence:

> I have bought 2 socks.

A pair of socks is quite obvious, 2 pairs of socks also, but what with 2 socks? 2 socks are a pair, but since you can't buy single socks, this 2 in the sentence could be interpreted as carrying the information that 2 pairs of socks were bought.

Comment: Buy one sock and get one for free!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A sock is an individual item of clothing. To buy two of them would thus indicate that you had bought, well, two socks—but these socks might not pair with each other; instead, they might be halves of different pairs. Thus, unless there was context that might suggest otherwise, I (and presumably most native speakers of English) would conclude that you had bought two individual items of clothing.

And yes, you can buy individual socks if you want.

Comment: maybe there's a business opportunity for single sock by the way

Answer (score -1):

Most (then ones I know) native speakers would interpret this as a slip of the tongue, and would assume you meant 2 pairs of socks.

This may also be interpreted as humorous, depending on the context of the sentence.